# How can let Chrome "Google Mail Checker" only show important mails?

Tags: google-chrome, gmail, google-chrome-extensions

I am using Chrome extension - [Google Mail Checker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-mail-checker/mihcahmgecmbnbcchbopgniflfhgnkff), but it shows every unread email in my inbox.

How can I show "Important and unread" mail only?

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to recommend you to check [Checker Plus for Gmail™](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/checker-plus-for-gmail/oeopbcgkkoapgobdbedcemjljbihmemj) out. It provides much more options and features than the original [Google Mail Checker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-mail-checker/mihcahmgecmbnbcchbopgniflfhgnkff).

After installing the extension, open it's option page and navigate to the "Accounts/Labels" tab. You can configure which labels (*e.g.*, Important Mail) to monitor.